# Access denied to a mysql database using python code, for which I have super user privileges

Tags: python, mysql, database, ubuntu, exception

I am running a python code on Ubuntu 12.04, which connects to Mysql database. When creating the database I made sure that I have super user privileges.

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'hammouc'@'localhost';
 +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for hammouc@localhost                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'hammouc'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret>    |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mimclib`.* TO 'hammouc'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However when I run the code in Ubuntu shell. I have many exceptions as the following

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'hammouc'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

Comment: You didn't provide the password in your python code?

Comment: I want to use the code without providing the password. Is there anyway to change the privileges so I can access without providing password?

Answer (score 0):

Using mysql, if the user has a password, it must be provided.  The only way to connect to mysql without specifying a password is to define a user without a password (this is discouraged).  If you don't want to specify the password in the script, then you must either ask the user for it, or read it from a file.